Maven tool window disappeared in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1
The Maven tool window has disappeared from my Maven-driven project, with pom.xml file present.
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Ultimate Edition).
Here is a screen shot showing:

No Maven tool available
The Maven plugin is activated


Running the latest version of macOS (Sonoma, 14.4.1).

My Question is similar to How to get the Maven project window in Intellij 14 | Update: cannot see the right side "tab bar" with Maven project. But that Question is for a much older version of IntelliJ. The Answers there no longer apply.

Have you tried to delete .idea directory and imported the project from scratch?

@khmarbaise Deleting .idea folder from within the project folder solved the problem. Thank you.  If you provide an Answer, I'll accept it. Or I can.

This is pretty much the go to solution when IntelliJ becomes confused. Congratulations on switching.

Delete .idea folder

Quit IntelliJ
Delete the .idea folder from within your project folder.
Restart IntelliJ, re-open your project.

All should be good then.

Thanks a lot. I suffered from exactly the same problem and did according to your suggestion and eventually opened the project properly with Java aspect

If deleting .idea folder does not work, you may try this

In Intellij select the directory you need to add as module, and
press Shift twice
Search for "Add Maven Project" and select it



Delete the .iml file
Deleting the .idea directory didn't work for me.
But closing the project in Intellij, deleting the <project-name>.iml file, and then re-opening the project did the trick.

for beginners, click on "maven-build-scripts-found" button of the notification from intellij.
i found this solution on second week of start working with intellij.
Maven Build Scripts Found - IntelliJ - What are the build scripts, where are they cached?
